# Ospf multicasting with two different group

Tags: routing, ospf, layer3, multicast

Suppose I have one ospf network where two multicast group exists. And some routers is ospf which belongs to one group or multiple group **(Like:  routers E, H)** and router is layer3 router **(Like:  routers A, C, K)**, not ospf router. Like given below:

[image]

I divided the whole network into two parts Multicastgroup 1 and Multicastgroup 2.Like given below:
[image]
[image]

I have some confusions which are given below:

**Confusion 1::** We know that all routers which belongs to same group one multicast address. So my question is routers which belongs to different subnets, but they are also using same multicast address? For example the adjacent link between routers H and I belongs to one subnet and the adjacent link between routers I and J belongs to another subnet , but they are using one multicast address i. e. belongs to same group. Am I correct?

**Confusion 2::** The adjacent link between two routers should belongs to same group? I mean the adjacent link between two routers, is there possible one interface of adjacent link belongs to one group and another interface belongs to another group **or** is there possible one interface belongs to any group and another is layer3 interface?

**Confusion 3::** We see that in routers A, C, K don't running routing protocol ospf. Suppose one router belongs to group 1,say J  floods the routing protocol information when that information comes into interfaces of layer3 routers A, C, K they just route routing protocol information and don't exchange the routing protocol information because layer3 routers A, C, K running upto layer3 but routing protocol information is application database? Am I correct?

**Confusion 4::** When one router interface belongs to one multicastgroup, when that interface get another multicastgroup routing protocol information, both exchange the routing protocol information? I mean group1 router interface could exchange the routing protocol information with group2 router interface?

**Confusion 5::** Router one interface could run more than one than one routing protocol? I mean router one interface could belongs to both multicast groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OSPF uses a link-local multicast group that does not cross a router. Each OSPF multicast is confined to a single link.

There is nothing about your diagrams that would have an OSPF multicast on more than two routers. In fact, it would be a best practice to use unicast for your diagram.

Every interface on a router would use the OSPF multicast groups for all routers (`224.0.0.5` for IPv4, `FF02::5` for IPv6) and DR/BDR (`224.0.0.6` for IPv4, `FF02::6` for IPv6). Those multicasts are confined to the link on which they are originate, and are not propagated across a router to other links.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135292/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-ospf-multicasting-with-two-different-group).

Comment: hierarchical routing protocol is also application layer protocol?

Comment: Routing protocols are applications that run on a router. They use transport protocols (RIP/UDP, EIGRP/RTP, OSPF/OSPF, BGP/TCP). OSPF is hierarchical in that multi-area OSPF implementations require that all areas connect to Area 0 (backbone). OSPF areas (other than Area 0) will only exchange information with Area 0. You cannot have `Area0<->Area1<->Area2` (unless you use a virtual link that connects Area 2 to Area 0) because Area 1 and Area 2 cannot exchange routing information with each other except through Area 0.

Comment: OSPF/OSPF mean---- ospf is application layer as well as transport layer?

Comment: OSPF is an application that has its own transport protocol that it uses to exchange information. The transport protocol does not have a separate name, only protocol number 89. EIGRP has its own transport protocol (number 88), but Cisco named it RTP.

Comment: So hierarchical routing protocol is actually protocol or it's actually structure(Physical table)?

Comment: It is an application that requires a hierarchy. Really just OSPF and IS-IS require a hierarchy (basically the same way, although the terminology and details are different).

Comment: Suppose connection between `Area1 border router` and Area0 router is broken, then virtual link will be created temporarily between `Area1 border router` and `Area2 border router`. Then now Area2 could exchange data with Area1 directly through virtual link without Area0 temporarily. Am I correct?

Comment: "_Then now Area2 could exchange data with Area1 directly through virtual link without Area0 temporarily_" No. A virtual link must be created between Area 0 and an area not directly connected to Area 0. Other areas cannot directly communicate. Also, virtual links do not automatically get created, they must be configured.

Comment: @AlokMaity, it may be confusing, but routers are not in areas. Router interfaces are placed in areas. That is how you have an ABR: one interface is in Area 0, and other interfaces are in a different area.

Comment: Suppose Area2 is disconnected with Area0, then we create virtual link Area0<->Area1<->Area2. In this case Area1 and Area2 directly communicate without Area0? My question is how Area0 is involved to communicate between Area1 and Area2 because they are directly connected?

Comment: No. Other areas can only communicate through Area 0. That is the rule. Allowing other areas to directly communicate can lead to routing loops, so an area other than Area 0 cannot directly communicate with any other area but Area 0. It is a pretty simple rule.

Comment: But link between Area0 and Area2 is broken, so how Area2 communicate with Area1 through Area0?

Comment: You must configure a virtual link between an isolated area and Area 0. That is basically a tunnel specific to OSPF. The remote area will communicate with Area 0 through the virtual link.

Comment: is it possible one host uses both ipv4 as well as ipv6?

Comment: OSPFv2 is only for IPv4. There is also now OSPFv3 that can have address families (IPv4 family and IPv6 family). It all goes back to the complicated way OSPF exchanges information. Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols.

Comment: Regardless of ospf, suppose any host like me, you, could we use both ipv4, ipv6 at the same time for different application?

Comment: Router interfaces can be configured with multiple different layer-3 protocols, e.g. IPv4, IPX, AppleTalk, IPv6, etc., and the router can route traffic for all of them, but there will be a different routing table for each. You can also configure your host to run multiple routing protocols on interfaces. The protocols are separate, incompatible protocols, so they do not interact or interfere with each other.

Comment: Ospf doing multicasting, so could we use TCP as layer4 protocol for ospf application? Because TCP doesn't support multicasting and broadcasting? So We could use UDP?

Comment: As I explained to you before, [OSPF has its own transport protocol (protocol 89)](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) with its own handshakes, selection of the master, and methods for transferring data. On the other hand, BGP uses TCP.